# duplicate tab content with different information loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

1. I have two tab that have the same content-structure but the information that I have to load in each one is different. I do not want to duplicate the html code, how can I do it and also how can I indicate to each form which are the value to load in each tab.

   `<div id="tabs"> 
     <ul> 
       <li><a href="Tab1">Tab1</a></li> 
       <li><a href="Tab2">Tab2</a></li> 
     </ul> 
     <div id="Tab1"> 
       // some html dropdown, textfield, etc 
     </div> 
   </div>`

Now the tab1 loaded but tab2 dont work fine. I try somethig like this but I loose all my event in tab2

`var clonedDiv = jQuery('#Tab1').clone(); 
clonedDiv.attr('id', 'Tab2'); 
jQuery('#tabs').append(clonedDiv);`

Comment: 2. ... ... ... ?

Comment: We will need more informations and some code to help you.

Comment: Edit the question, don't add clarifications in comments.